# How to tshark with option -T fields list information each layer in packet?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tshark

I have a file pcap.pcap and i want print all fields for each packet with option -T
my command: tshark -r filepcap.pcap -T fields -e tcap.begin  -e tcap.continue  -e tcap.end -e tcap.tid -E separator="|"

but on console display each line:

```
(begin|continue|end|tid)
1,1|||04:1e:4f:30,a1:04:07:a7
1|1||84:10:01:6f,04:1b:65:64
1|||03:fa:58:1a
```

I see each line have 2 layer TCAP or CAMEL, and can't mapping fields with tid of it.

Example line:

```
1|1||84:10:01:6f,04:1b:65:64
```

id1 = 84:10:01:6f id2=04:1b:65:64
and i can't mapping them (id1 or id2) with status is begin or continue

Please help me if you can.

Comment: Do you have an example capture file? Have you checked that a `1` value for `begin` isn't equivalent to `1,0` (meaning if the the second is 0, it's omitted)?

Comment: i sorry, i edited console, display right is: 1,1|||04:1e:4f:30,a1:04:07:a7
1|1||84:10:01:6f,04:1b:65:64
1|||03:fa:58:1a (it not have value 0)

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/i8R4jbsu5q5u1UNz9

Answer (score 0):

If you're mostly interested in the contents of the `tcap.tid` field, you could modify your `tshark` commmand so that you only display those packets where the field is present, and you could also display the tid first, rather than last, e.g.:

```
tshark -r filepcap.pcap -Y "tcap.tid" -T fields -e tcap.tid -e tcap.begin -e tcap.continue -e tcap.end -E separator="|"
```

Comment: thanks mr,                                                                                                       with your command i have resurt as: 
`61:36:31:f8,04:0e:46:6a,61:36:01:1d,ac:00:01:a6,88:1a:1a:a1||1,1|1`                                                                                      my problem is can't mapping tid with status (begin,continue, end) of layer.                                                    as result: i have 3 tid and 3 status (2 begin and 1 continue) but can't mapping tid and status..